# What are the correct permissions for a non-root user in Red Hat 7?

Tags: permissions, rhel, oracle-linux

I imported a pre-made [Oracle Developer VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html), from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html), into VirtualBox and the oracle user (which is not root), can't do anything without using sudo, for the most part.

For example, any file I want to edit, `nano somefile` or copy and paste will not work without sudo.  From a gui such as nautilus, I can't paste either.

```
ls -ld $HOME
drwx------. 37 oracle oracle 4096 Mar  9 14:53 /home/oracle
```

I see the flags are wrong, but how can I fix it?  What are my permissions as a non-root user, *across the system*, supposed to be by default?  I did not change the built-in oracle user.  I know I can use `chmod`, but I feel like I'm missing something key here.

Comment: What makes you think the flags you are seeing above are incorrect?  A user's home directory is generally not set to world-readable or writeable, and is usually restricted to the owning user, in this case oracle.  It does seem a little odd that the group has no permissions.  What user are you logged in as, that you are trying to make edits from?

Comment: @DonSimon Maybe I am wrong then.  I am used to being Admin on Windows, so it was odd to me to have to type in sudo gedit to edit something outside of ~/Documents (which I found out does work.)